# Digitally Signed Word 2013 Document can be modified in SharePoint 2013 document library, without invalidating Digital Signatures

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, office-365

1. i created SharePoint 2013 Document library named "Issue Vouchers"
2. i designed a template for my library with an empty signature line.
3. My template contains various "Document Properties" embedded in document      template as quick fields. Document properties can only be edited by Library Admin.

Following is the process that has enabled editing of my signed document in SharePoint 2013

1. As a result of workflow activity document was generated in accordance with template(with an empty signature line) in my SharePoint Document library "Issue Vouchers".
2. User was emailed automatically to sign a concerned Issue Voucher.
3. User signed that document.
4. But when as a library admin i edit one of my document properties in Sharepoint 2013 Library (that are reflected as quick feilds in a document) it should immediatly invalidate digital signatures . But that residing document with reflected changes is perfectly validating digital signatures for that issue voucher.

which i think is impossible as SharePoint does not have access to private keys of Active Directory Users. or document properties are not used while generation of its md5 hash.

Is it a bug or It is meant to work that way???

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience with the signed documents however, you might want to look at declaring the documents as records when they are signed and it will prevent editing these items.